# Replace the records with ******** partially in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to replace my column with name (Accountno) partially as below using SQL in DB2 IBM, Also I dont want to create a new column need to make changes in the same column

Before Accountno:

```
234567734
987652309
```

After Accountno:

```
23*****34
98*****09
```

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Are all 9 digits?

Comment: All are 9 digits and data type is int

Comment: After some reading and asking around, it seems that you cant combine int and str values in an int type column, so the the only option I think is to create another column of type str.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dynamic Data Masking](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-dynamic-data-masking-in-sql-server-2016-to-protect-sensitive-data/)

```sql
 ALTER TABLE Account   ALTER COLUMN Accountno nvarchar(10) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION= 'partial(2,"XXXXX",2)');
```

Comment: SQL State: 42601 Vendor Code: -199 Message: [SQL0199] Keyword COLUMN not expected. Valid tokens: ADD LOG NOT SET DATA DROP ALTER CHECK APPEND ATTACH DETACH. Cause . . . . . :   The keyword COLUMN was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword COLUMN.  The partial list of valid tokens is ADD LOG NOT SET DATA DROP ALTER CHECK APPEND ATTACH DETACH. This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the unexpected keyword.  The error may be earlier in the statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be valid up to this point. Recovery

Comment: This script was for example, but i modify it and you can use it. This feature has been added since sql2016 and your version should not be less than that. It is also better to read the link of the article completely

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the first and last two characters of account number. Then replace the middle characters with "*" by repeating it 5 times.

```
 UPDATE test_table
 SET    Accountno = SUBSTR(Accountno, 1, 2) 
        || REPEAT('*', LENGTH(Accountno) - 4) 
        || SUBSTR(Accountno, LENGTH(Accountno) - 1, 2)  


   sample output:
   22*****89
   34*****24
```

Comment: This was working but the replacement is happening like this 23*******,
But Iam looking like this 23*****34

Comment: it is working for me as seen on my example output. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET accoountno =
       substr(accoountno, 1, 2) || '*****' ||
       substr(accoountno, char_length(accoountno) - 1, 2);
```

Comment: update kwdb108T.TDM_KWCBASE
set CACHABA =
       substr(CACHABA, 1, 2) || '*****' ||
       substr(CACHABA, char_length(CACHABA) - 1, 2)
Below is the error:

SQL State: 22018 Vendor Code: -420 Message: [SQL0420] Value for cast argument not valid. Cause . . . . . :   A character in the argument for a casting function was not correct or the argument could not be converted to a numeric value. Recovery  . . . :   Change the argument to contain a valid representation of a value for the result data type.